# Linq - Dynamic Condition

Tags: c#, linq

I have the following query :-

I want to add one more condition which is dynamic, so if user passes `DATEOFBIRTH` it should be `e.DateOfBirth <= date`.

```
var data = ctx.Employee.Where(e => e.Id == Id
                                && e.Category == Category
                                && e.DateOfJoining <= date)
                                .Select(e => e)
                                .ToList();
```

How to condition dynamically?

Comment: Question isn't clear. What is `DATEOFBIRTH`, a `DateTime` or a string which means "filter by date of birth"? Where did you get stuck, what is the real issue?

Comment: If the DateOfBirth is choosen, there `where` condition should be appended by one more condition `e.DateOfBirth <= date`.. if user chooses DateOfAnniversary then it should be `e.DateOfAnniversary <= date`..

Comment: What means "chose" in this context? What is the ideal method signature for your requirement?

Comment: What is wrong with `&& (date == null ? true :  date <= e.DateOfBirth) ...`

Comment: It is used for calculation... whatever is passed to the method, it should be included in condition....if `DateOfBirth` is passed to method which fires this Linq query, then `DateOfBirth` condition has to be appended.

Answer (score 1):

You can use reflection to solve this problem but there is another idea that may helps you:

```
  var criteria = new Dictionary<string, Func<Employee, bool>>();

  var date = DateTime.Now;  //or any other value

  //Initialize your criterias   
  criteria.Add("DATEOFBIRTH", e => e.DateOfBirth <= date);
  criteria.Add("DateOfJoining", e => e.DateOfJoining <= date);

  var selectedValue = "DATEOFBIRTH";

  var data = ctx.Employee.Where(e => e.Id == id &&
                                     e.Category == Category &&
                                     criteria[selectedValue](e)).ToList();
```

So if you change the `selectedValue` the output will be based on corresponding criteria you are looking for.

Comment: +1 for the mention of reflection which would be a much more maintainable version. But this solution is also great as the conditions(criteria) can be put somewhere else and reused if necessary.

Comment: I would go for the dictionary over reflection. Serms mantainable too and you give access to filters that you want. With reflection, any Employee's property can be evaluated.

Answer (score 0):

Sounds like you're trying to do the following:

```
var employees = ctx.Employee.Where(e => e.Id == Id
                                        && e.Category == Category
                                        && e.DateOfJoining <= date);

if (!string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(DATEOFBIRTH))
{
    employees = employees.Where(e => e.DateOfBirth <= DATEOFBIRTH);
}

var data = employees.ToList();
```

You could also do the following, which is more concise, but since it looks like you are querying a database here, I would prefer the above approach since it doesn't include anything unnecessary in the query.

```
var data = ctx.Employee.Where(e => e.Id == Id && 
                                   e.Category == Category && 
                                   e.DateOfJoining <= date &&
                                   (string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(DATEOFBIRTH) ||
                                    e.DateOfBirth <= DATEOFBIRTH))
                       .ToList();
```

Answer (score 0):

From your comment:

> If the `DateOfBirth` is choosen, there where condition should be appended
>   by one more condition `e.DateOfBirth <= date`.. if user chooses
>   `DateOfAnniversary` then it should be `e.DateOfAnniversary <= date`

Then you could use:

```
var data = ctx.Employee
    .Where(e => e.Id == Id && e.Category == Category && e.DateOfJoining <= date);
```

Now, assuming that `filterbyDateOfBirth` and `filterbyDateOfAnniversary` are `bools`:

```
if(filterbyDateOfBirth)
    data = data.Where(e => e.DateOfBirth <= date);
if(filterbyDateOfAnniversary)
    data = data.Where(e => e.DateOfAnniversary <= date);

var list = data.ToList();
```

Due to LINQ's deferred execution  the database is  queried just once at `ToList`.